# How can I find out if the government paid to build a runway?

Tags: usa, non-towered-airport

I've heard rumors that the government paid to build a runway at a residential fly-in community in the mountains of North Carolina to have it available as an emergency landing strip.  I would appreciate suggestions of how to find out.  I tried calling the FAA but with the automated system, I found it impossible to reach a human being.

Thank you!

Comment: Funding sources for construction projects does not seem like an Aviation related question to me.

Comment: The question was in regards to a RUNWAY.  Somewhat Aviation-related, wouldn't you agree??

Comment: I would.  Airport construction funding and compliance with grant assurance stipulations are quite on topic in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

The FAA gives funds to airports through the [Airport Improvement Program (AIP)](https://www.faa.gov/airports/aip/grantapportion_data/) and that could include runway improvements. It's public money so the information is also public and should be in the Excel files on that page. If that isn't what you need, you can always [submit an FOIA request to the FAA](https://www.faa.gov/foia/foia_request/) for all information they have about the airport.

It's also possible that you could get more information from the state or county. They usually have at least some input into airport construction, because of local zoning laws, easements and so on. Even if the rumor is false and the runway is built on private land and paid for with private money, there may be county planning or landowner records. But that's definitely beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Local newspapers/etc are another good source since you'll see various govt officials and politicians bragging about tax dollars at work.

Comment: Normally a call to the local FSDO will yield the current expenditures, and the planned expenditures.  A FOI may be needed for all the information, which is often folders of studies, engineering plans and correspondence.

Comment: My thanks to each of you who responded.  I appreciate the information and will take it from here.

Comment: @Emma K. I'd be interested to hear what you found and how you did it.